# How to evaluate $\int x\cdot\sin x\cdot\text{cosec} \,3x \,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

Evaluvate integral $\int x\sin (x)\csc(3x) ~\mathrm{d}x$

**My Try**

Using a trigonometric identity I was able to simplify,

$$\int \frac{x\sin x}{3\sin x-4\sin^3x}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$=\int \frac{x}{3-4\sin^2x}~\mathrm{d}x$$

How can I proceed? Should I use a substitute for this? Any hint would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: OP instead of asking whether substitution is a good idea, why not, idk... try it?

Comment: I tried few but nothing seems working since theres $\sin^2 x term$. I tried $\sin x=tan\theta/2$

Comment: @emil [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+xsin%28x%29csc%283x%29dx) says that there is no elementary antiderivative

Comment: So does it mean that its impossible to integrate this? @DatBoi

Comment: @emil it means that the integral cannot be expressed using elementary functions like $\ln x , \sin x,...$.

Comment: @emil i suspect this is a definite intgeral question with limits $0\rightarrow \pi$ then it is a standard problem

Comment: There were no limits for this problem.

Comment: You could represent the denominator as an infinite series (as sin^2(x)<1), but I don't think this way you would be able to get a closed form answer. Are you sure you want a closed form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{gather*}
I=\int x\sin x\csc 3xdx\\
=\int \frac{xdx}{3-4\sin^{2} x}\\
Integrate\ by\ parts\ taking\ \\
F( x) =x\ as\ the\ first\ part\ and\ \\
G( x) =\frac{1}{3-4\sin^{2} x} as\ the\ second\ part\\
By\ integration\ of\ parts,\ \\
I=F( x)\int G( x) -\int F^{'}( x)\left(\int G( x) dx\right) dx\\
Now,\ \int G( x) dx=\int \frac{dx}{3-4\sin^{2} x} =\int \frac{\csc^{2} xdx}{3\csc^{2} x-4}\\
=\int \frac{\csc^{2} xdx}{3\left(\cot^{2} x+1\right) -4} =\int \frac{\csc^{2} xdx}{3\cot^{2} x-1}\\
Subsitute\ \cot x=t\\
\csc^{2} x=-dt\\
\ \int G( x) dx=\int \frac{-dt}{3t^{2} -1} =\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{3}}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} t-1}{\sqrt{3} t+1}\right) =\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{3}}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}\cot x-1}{\sqrt{3}\cot x+1}\right)\\
\\
=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{3}}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}\cos x-\sin x}{\sqrt{3}\cos x+\sin x}\right) =\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{3}}(\ln(\cos\left( x+\frac{\pi }{6}\right) -\ln\left(\cos\left( x-\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\right)\\
=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\left(\ln\left(\cos\left( x-\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\right) -\ln\left(\cos\left( x+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\right)\right)\\
So,\\
I=F( x)\int G( x) -\int F^{'}( x)\left(\int G( x) dx\right) dx\\
=\frac{x}{2\sqrt{3}}\left(\ln\left(\cos\left( x-\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\right) -\ln\left(\cos\left( x+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\right)\right) -\int \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\left(\ln\left(\cos\left( x-\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\right) -\ln\left(\cos\left( x+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\right)\right) dx
\end{gather*}
All you need to do now is to compute the antiderivative of ln(cos(x-a)).

Comment: ...and the last integral involves a $\operatorname{Li}_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I'll try to workout the rest of it.

Comment: @Parcly Taxel May I know what's meant by  $Li_2$ please?

Comment: @emil The dilogarithm.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int x\sin (x)\csc(3x) \,dx$$ One integration by parts
$$dv=\sin (x)\csc(3x) \,dx \implies v=\frac 1 {\sqrt 3}\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan (x)}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$ which could be transformed with logarithms.

So, what is left is to compute
$$J=\int \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan (x)}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$ which has a closed form. Have a look at [the monster](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BArcTanh%5BTan%5Bx%5D%2FSqrt%5B3%5D%5D%2Cx%5D).

Using @Ishraaq Parvez's answer
$$\int \log(\cos(x))\,dx=\frac{i}{2}  \text{Li}_2\left(-e^{2 i x}\right)+\frac{i x^2}{2}-x \log
   \left(1+e^{2 i x}\right)+x \log (\cos (x))$$
Not much more funny !